# PHP Mess Detector giving false positives

Tags: php, coding-style, conventions, phpmd

I'm working with an open source project and thought it would be a good idea to implement automated code revisions with *phpmd*.

It showed me many coding mistakes that im fixing already. But one of them made me curious.

Consider the following method:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param string $pluginName
 */
public static function loadPlugin($pluginName){
    $path = self::getPath()."plugins/$pluginName/";
    $bootPath = $path.'boot.php';
    if(\is_dir($path)){

        //Autoload classes
        self::$classloader->add("", $path);

        //If theres a "boot.php", run it
        if(is_file($bootPath)){
            require $bootPath;
        }

    }else{
        throw new \Exception("Plugin not found: $pluginName");
    }
}
```

Here, phpmd says that [Else is never necessary](https://phpmd.org/rules/cleancode.html#elseexpression)

> ...An if expression with an else branch is never necessary. You can
>   rewrite the conditions in a way that the else is not necessary and the
>   code becomes simpler to read. ...

`is_dir` will return false whenever the given path is a file or simply does not exist, so, in my opinion, this test is not valid at all.

Is there a way to fix it or maybe simply ignore cases like this one?

Comment: Just a tip. There is Sniff alternative in CodeSniffer: https://github.com/object-calisthenics/phpcs-calisthenics-rules#1-only-x-level-of-indentation-per-method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative to the structure is something like this:

```
public static function loadPlugin( $pluginName ) {
    $path = self::getPath() . "plugins/$pluginName/";
    $bootPath = $path . 'boot.php';
    if( \is_dir( $path ) ) {
        // Autoload classes
        self::$classloader->add( "", $path );
        // If theres a "boot.php", run it
        if ( is_file( $bootPath ) ) {
            require $bootPath;
        }
        // A return here gets us out of the function, removing the need for an "else" statement
        return;
    }

    throw new \Exception( "Plugin not found: $pluginName" );
}
```

While I'm not sure it's *the solution*, it is a technique to avoid the `else` condition.  Else conditions can add complexity when trying to read the code, and allowing the function to "flow" without else conditions can make them more readable.

Comment: Its a good solution, the warning does not shows up. But I had to move the `return`  outside that if, because that file is optional in the plugin structure.

Comment: In any case, I dont think just removing all the _else_ clauses is a good idea, since its a basic decicion statement present in all programming languages. Do you know if there's a way of disabling this test in PHPMd?

Comment: I personally don't use PHPMd.  I have grown to absolutely **love** PHPStorm (it's an IDE).  It's SO good, and it provides code formattting tools, hints, suggestions, etc.  My code is way better since using it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

I don't use `phpmd`, but it's clear that your `if` statement is a guard clause. Guard clauses don't need `else` branches, you can safely refactor your code like this:

```
/**
 * @param string $pluginName
 * @throws \Exception if plugin cannot be found
 */
public static function loadPlugin($pluginName)
{
    $path = self::getPath() . "plugins/$pluginName/";
    if (!\is_dir($path)) {
        throw new \Exception("Plugin not found: $pluginName");
    }

    // Autoload classes
    self::$classloader->add("", $path);

    // If there is a "boot.php", run it
    $bootPath = $path . 'boot.php';
    if (is_file($bootPath)) {
        require $bootPath;
    }
}
```

Further reading:

- [Use Guard Clauses for all the special cases](http://refactoring.com/catalog/replaceNestedConditionalWithGuardClauses.html)
- ["Return early" vs "Minimize returns" balance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36707/should-a-function-have-only-one-return-statement)